# How to perform near interaction using hand gesture in Perception Simulation?

Tags: hololens, hololens-emulator

I need to enter the username and password for one of the hololense application. I am able to perform the air tap for the far interaction using hand gestures. But, I couldn't perform the near interaction to enter value from the keyboard.

[image: Keyboard Simulation]

How can I simulate the keyboard action in the virtual keyboard? I tried to use Point Pose, but it is not working.

Answer (score 2):

The system keyboard should be able to enter values through near interaction.

After testing, we found that you can hold the left or right Alt keys(in your physical keyboard) to move the hand, and make the hand mesh **tap** the system keyboard. Specifically, once the hand touches the keyboard, the button color will become white. And at this time, the key is to minimize the touch time to avoid triggering other input events. If you make it, the value will be displayed in the input field.

Comment: For hand mesh tap, which button needs to be pressed from the physical keyboard? I have used the enter key for the Far interaction. But, It is not working for the near interaction

Comment: @Subburaj Press Alt + W/A/S/D to move the hand to interact with the system keyboard. The short touch time will trigger a tap event from the system keyboard.